# Meteor: Using Web Worker

Tags: meteor, web-worker

I want to use web worker to play a sequence of sounds that depends on Meteor's Session variables. So I can't really put it in the public folder.

Does it I mean I must wrap it into a package in order to use web worker?

Comment: I believe you should `.postMessage` to your worker in order to send them some data. Note that worker will be evaluated in an isolated environment, so it won't have any direct access to **Meteor** features.

Comment: If that's the case, then I guess it's fine to put the worker in the public folder. I just have to re-implement the worker.

Comment: One unexpected "bug" I ran into is that changing a script in public folder does not cause meteor to run the changed script, so I have to visit the script's page in my browser in order for meteor to recognize that the script has been changed and not use the cached/stale version.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor is based on `connect`, so, you can put the file `worker.js` outside the app folder (make it not loaded), then use your self-defining router
`.use('/worker.js', FILEPATH)`.

Comment: Meteor `build`s won't find the file unless it's in `public` or `private` folders. One could use this method if the `.js` file was placed in `private`, but, since it's static, putting the `.js` file in the `public` folder will not require any code to make it be served.

Answer (score -1):

The `/public` folder is not for scripts. Sounds like a client-side task – put it in the `/client` folder (maybe inside a `Meteor.startup()` function).

Comment: Not correct. Some scripts that are about to be loaded dynamically can be put in the `/public` folder. It is not a bad idea at all.

Comment: If it's in the `client` folder, then it will be part of the main js bundle. Web workers do not share code or data with the main bundle, so it MUST go in `public` in this case.